python code not working properly in python terminal but working in idle editor
I am using python to encrypt and decrypt stream ciphers. It works perfectly fine on the idle editor shell when I run it but I get messed up outputs when I try to run the code with the python terminal (opening the python file from file explorer). It works on the terminal when decrypting a small word but any additional spaces or numbers messes it up but it doesn't mess up when run through idle.
I have no idea what's wrong and have tried searching up solutions but have not found anything.
import random
import urllib.request
from operator import add

word_site = "https://www.mit.edu/~ecprice/wordlist.10000"

class colours:
    RED = '\033[93m'
    WHITE = '\033[0m'
while True:
    print ('Type [e] to encrypt a message')
    print ('Type [d] to decrypt a message')
    print ('Type [q] to quit')

    select = input ('Selection: ')

    if select.lower() == 'q':
        quit()

    elif select.lower() == 'e':

        open_site = urllib.request.urlopen(word_site)
        words  = open_site.read().splitlines()

        while True:
            generate_key = str(random.choices([line for line in words],  k=1))
            key = (generate_key[3:-2])
            if len(key) > 5 and len(key) < 15:
                break
            else:
                continue

        msg = input ('Enter a message to be encrypted: ')
        split_msg = [*msg]

        keystream = ''.join(key[i % len(key)]  for i in range(len(msg)))
        print ('Your stream key is: ',key)

        plain_num = ([ord(c) for c in msg])
        
        key_num = ([ord(c) for c in keystream])
        
        added_num = (list(map(add, plain_num, key_num)))
        cipher_num = []
        for i in added_num:
            cipher_num.append(i % 128)


        print ('Your encrypted text is below:')
        encrypted_txt = "".join(map(chr,cipher_num))
        print (encrypted_txt)
        
        
    elif select.lower() == 'd':
        cipher_txt = input ('Enter cipher text to decrypt: ')

        cipher_key = input ('Enter key used to ecrypt the text: ')

        keystream_txt = ''.join(cipher_key[i % len(cipher_key)]  for i in range(len(cipher_txt)))

        cipher_txt_num = ([ord(c) for c in cipher_txt])

        cipher_key_num = ([ord(c) for c in keystream_txt])

        cipher_txt_num_added = ([i + 128 for i in cipher_txt_num])

        subtracted_ciphers = ([a - b for a, b in zip(cipher_txt_num_added, cipher_key_num)])

        print ('Your decrypted text is below:')
        print (''.join(map(chr,subtracted_ciphers)))

I was expecting the code to work on both idle and the terminal. I thought the python terminal may have been outdated but I installed them both at the same time and it does say its python 3.12.

Please read and apply https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.
